# rails server not starting any solutions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

when I tried `rails s` after `bundle install`

```
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Exiting
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/act
ive_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': cannot load such file -- bcrypt (L
oadError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-
3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-
3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `block in load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-
3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:639:in `new_constants_in'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-
3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-
3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-2.2.3/l
ib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-2.2.3/l
ib/devise/models.rb:97:in `const_get'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-2.2.3/l
ib/devise/models.rb:97:in `block (2 levels) in devise'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-2.2.3/l
ib/devise/models.rb:92:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-2.2.3/l
ib/devise/models.rb:92:in `block in devise'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-2.2.3/l
ib/devise/models.rb:123:in `devise_modules_hook!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-2.2.3/l
ib/devise/models.rb:90:in `devise'
        from C:/Users/alokkumar.jha/Desktop/BioFlow/GVKbio_Flow/app/models/user.
rb:5:in `<class:User>'
        from C:/Users/alokkumar.jha/Desktop/BioFlow/GVKbio_Flow/app/models/user.
rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-
3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-
3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `block in load_file'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-
3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:639:in `new_constants_in'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-
3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:468:in `load_file'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-
3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:353:in `require_or_load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-
3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in `load_missing_constant'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-
3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-
3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-
3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-
3.2.6/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `block in constantize'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-
3.2.6/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-
3.2.6/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in `constantize'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-
3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:554:in `get'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-
3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:588:in `constantize'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-2.2.3/l
ib/devise.rb:267:in `get'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-2.2.3/l
ib/devise/mapping.rb:77:in `to'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-2.2.3/l
ib/devise/mapping.rb:72:in `modules'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-2.2.3/l
ib/devise/mapping.rb:89:in `routes'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-2.2.3/l
ib/devise/mapping.rb:156:in `default_used_route'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-2.2.3/l
ib/devise/mapping.rb:66:in `initialize'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-2.2.3/l
ib/devise.rb:301:in `new'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-2.2.3/l
ib/devise.rb:301:in `add_mapping'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-2.2.3/l
ib/devise/rails/routes.rb:208:in `block in devise_for'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-2.2.3/l
ib/devise/rails/routes.rb:207:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-2.2.3/l
ib/devise/rails/routes.rb:207:in `devise_for'
        from C:/Users/alokkumar.jha/Desktop/BioFlow/GVKbio_Flow/config/routes.rb
:6:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2
.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:282:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2
.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:282:in `eval_block'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2
.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:260:in `draw'
        from C:/Users/alokkumar.jha/Desktop/BioFlow/GVKbio_Flow/config/routes.rb
:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-
3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-
3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-
3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-
3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.6
/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.6
/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.6
/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.6
/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.6
/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-
3.2.6/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:78:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-
3.2.6/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:78:in `execute'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.6
/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
        from C:in `execute_if_updated'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.6
/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:66:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.6
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.6
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.6
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.6
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.6
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.6
/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.6
/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
        from C:/Users/alokkumar.jha/Desktop/BioFlow/GVKbio_Flow/config/environme
nt.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-
3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-
3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-
3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-
3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from C:/Users/alokkumar.jha/Desktop/BioFlow/GVKbio_Flow/config.ru:3:in `
block in <main>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib
/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib
/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
        from C:/Users/alokkumar.jha/Desktop/BioFlow/GVKbio_Flow/config.ru:in `ne
w'
        from C:/Users/alokkumar.jha/Desktop/BioFlow/GVKbio_Flow/config.ru:in `<m
ain>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib
/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib
/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib
/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.6
/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib
/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib
/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.6
/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.6
/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.6
/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.6
/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is just an error message dump - no description of context or attempts to research / fix therefore it is unanswerable as it stands

Comment: Do you have bcrypt gem in your gemfile?

Comment: Did you correctly install the bcrypt gem? Open the Gemfile.lock and search for bcrypt. Please confirm if you have it or not?

Answer (score 0):

If you have run "bundle install" to install bcrypt, just restart the rails server.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is very clear that you either not installed  `bcrypt gem` or the `bcrypt gem` is not successful.
Open your gem file and add the below line and run bundle install. Be sure to restart the server.

```
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.1.rc1', :require => 'bcrypt'
```